# Using definite article with verb infinitive (“al”)

Tags: gramática

I saw one Spanish translation of a sentence "*Let You Go*" and it was translated like this:

"*Me equivoqué al dejarte ir*"

I think it should be "irte" or other verb in this context, but the question of this topic - why "*al*" is used with verb instead of "*a*", "*que*" or "*de*" (which would mean "to")? My guess - here "Me equivoqué al dejarte" would mean "*I was wrong in letting you*..."

I base this guess on other phrase I encountered the same day in a movie: "*Y al hacerlo*" - was translated to English as "In doing so".

But seems unusual for me to see definite article (a + el) located before a verb, not a noun.

Is it like this only with preposition "*a*" with masculine article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro/ARCHIVO-Foro/Al%20ante%20infinitivo.htm), there are two possible grammatical explanations (as well as two possible meanings) for "al" (which **always remains in that masculine, singular form**) before infinitives:

> En la combinación al + infinitivo, la partícula *al* parece comportarse como conjunción, ya que no introduce grupos nominales, pues el infinitivo en este caso admite sujetos expresos (*al salir el sol / al enterarse su padre*). Otra característica es la alternancia del sentido temporal (*al salir a la calle, se dio cuenta de que había olvidado la cartera*) con el causal (*al no tener dinero, no pudo comprar el piso*).
>
> Para algunos gramáticos la partícula *al* en la combinación *al* + infinitivo es una combinación de preposición y artículo (*[a] [el salir el sol]*), mientras que para otros esta partícula es una conjunción subordinante y por tanto indivisible (*[al] [salir el sol]*), ya que no introduce grupos nominales ni pronominales.

According to the text transcribed above, some grammarians consider "al" to be the result of merging the preposition "a" with the article "el", while others find it to be an indivisible subordinating conjunction.

Moreover, infinitival phrases or clauses introduced by "al" can be temporal or causative in meaning.

In:

- Me equivoqué al dejarte ir.

"al dejarte ir" combines, I think, time and cause: I was wrong when I let you go, and letting you go expalins my mistake.

Comment: thank you, Gustavson. Seems clear now overall. I think, each case is slightly individual, but at least I have some understanding of "al + inf" to base on. In addition to this, I have amended related question after your duplicate pronoun correction. As you are into this already, could you please comment in https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32013/23475 ?

Comment: Perdón, pero no le encuentro sentido a *al dejar irte*. ¿Cómo lo usarías?

Comment: @rsanchez Igual que "al dejarte ir" (más comùn). El apartado 16.4.3 del Manual de la última gramática de la Real Academia Española dice que los pronombres enclíticos pueden aparecer en cualquier posición –salvo muy contadas excepciones– con respecto a la perífrasis a la cual acompañan, debido a que la perífrasis es considerada un solo verbo, y no dos o tres verbos distintos. Así, podemos decir: *No te debería dejar ir / No debería dejarte ir / No debería dejar irte.*

Comment: @rsanchez Mira por ejemplo el poema "Decirte" en esta página: https://www.poemas-del-alma.com/pdfs/193712.pdf: *Algún día dejaré
de ser cobarde,
iré a buscarte,
 para decirte
 que no he podido olvidarte,
que fui un completo idiota
**al dejar irte**, ...*

Comment: No creo que se trate de una perífrasis. No está listada acá: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Per%C3%ADfrasis_verbales_del_espa%C3%B1ol No hay resultados en ngram para "dejar irte". La relación en google search es de un millón a diez mil.

Comment: @rsanchez Más allá de cualquier estadística y definición, cualquier hablante de español sabe que "No debería dejar irte" y "Fui un idiota al dejar irte" son oraciones gramaticalmente correctas. "dejarte ir" es más común pero eso no invalida la otra forma.

Comment: @rsanchez En google books (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dejar+irte%22&tbm=bks&ei=rWvJXcv-B6G65OUP-8WfyAE&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiLiYr6quLlAhUhHbkGHfviBxk4FBDy0wMIdA&biw=1100&bih=603&dpr=1.25) hay varios ejemplos correctos de "dejar irte" (excepto algunos que duplican "te").

Comment: Que no dupliquen el *te* conté cinco en total. Soy hablante de español y me parecen incorrectas :) No es una perífrasis, así que la regla que citaste no aplica. Para mí tiene tanto sentido como cambiar *dejarte bailar* por *dejar bailarte*. Lo que induce al error es la combinación con un verbo que puede ser pronominal como *ir*.

Comment: @rsanchez A pesar de que me siguen sonando bien, creo que tienes razón. Voy a eliminar esos ejemplos de mi respuesta. Es más: estoy pensando que la duplicación del pronombre sería correcta (uno corresponde al OD, y el otro al verbo pronominal).