# Dejarte irte, dejarte ir, dejar irte

Tags: verbo-pronominal, clíticos

A partir de una serie de comentarios intercambiados con @rsanchez en [este otro hilo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32014/using-definite-article-with-verb-infinitive-al/32015?noredirect=1#comment57302_32015), me gustaría conocer la opinión de los colegas del sitio sobre las frases verbales en negritas:

> (1) **Dejarte irte** fue un error.
>
> (2) **Dejarte ir** fue un error.
>
> (3) **Dejar irte** fue un error.

Hasta hoy, (1) me parecía incorrecta (por la duplicación del pronombre) y las otras dos, correctas. La oración (3) sería equivalente a:

(4) Dejar que te fueras fue un error.

Luego del intercambio con @rsanchez y su tenaz oposición, me permití dudar.

Creo que (1) sería correcta porque el primer "te" es objeto directo y el segundo, marca pronominal del verbo "irse", del mismo modo que serían posibles dos pronombres en:

(5) **La / Lo** dejé ir**se**.

En (2), el verbo no es "irse" sino "ir", en el sentido de dejar ir a alguien a cualquier lugar (NO marcharse):

- Me pidió ir al bar y la dejé ir (al bar).

Sigo teniendo alguna duda con (3).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Según entiendo (1) y (2) son correctas, aunque (1) suena tanto a frase redundante que casi ningún hablante la articularía naturalmente.

> (1) Dejarte irte fue un error.
>   (2) Dejarte ir fue un error.

Entre estas dos la única diferencia es que (1) usa la forma pronominal  de *ir*, mientras que (2) usa la forma básica. La forma básica es mucho menos frecuente con este significado ("marcharse, apartarse, abandonar un lugar"), pero se prefiere por la cacofonía que produce la forma pronominal al repetirse el pronombre. Está claro que es correcto usar otro pronombre en ese lugar, por ejemplo:

> (1') Dejarte llevarlo fue un error.

de manera que en principio no hay por qué no permitir (1).

La frase (3) es en mi opinión un error porque no llena la estructura de argumentos propia de *dejar*, que puede adoptar dos patrones alternativos:

(a) *dejar* + objeto + infinitivo (*dejarte ir*)
(b) *dejar* + *que* + subordinada (*dejar que te vayas*)

En (a), que es el tipo de patrón del que estamos tratando, el **objeto** de *dejar* refiere al **sujeto** de la subordinada infinitiva. Con ejemplos:

> *dejar**te** comer* = *dejar que **tú** comas*
>   *dejar**la** vivir* = *dejar que **ella** viva*
>   *dejar**nos** ver* = *dejar que **nosotros** veamos*

Es decir que en (3) falta ese objeto directo de *dejar*. Y no podemos suponer que en *dejar irte* ese pronombre *-te* corresponda al objeto de *dejar* porque [los clíticos ascienden](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascenso_de_cl%C3%ADtico) pero nunca descienden, es decir: un pronombre dentro de una subordinada puede "trepar" fuera de la subordinada y unirse al verbo principal externo a la misma, pero el proceso opuesto no existe.

Comment: Gracias, Pablo. "dejar irte" sigue sin sonarme mal, pero debe ser por la costumbre de oírlo o leerlo.